# prestashop-create new form with ajax onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, prestashop

Hi i'm new with prestashop 1.6 and i use jquery's $.ajax to call a PHP script . what i wan,t is to create new form when i click on button and this is my code :

in the catproduct.php :

```
public function clickme(){

$html = '<a href="#" class="displayForm">Click me</a>
         <div id="myFormm"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $( ".displayForm" ).click(function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: "'._MODULE_DIR_.$this->name.'/ajax.php",
              context: document.body,
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                $( "#myFormm" ).html( data );
                alert( "Load was performed." );
            });


        })
    </script>';



return $html;

}


public function renderForm()
{
    $fields_form = array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Add new category'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('FCI'),
                    'name' => 'FCI',
            ),
            ),

            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save')
            )
        ),
    );
    $helper = new HelperForm();
    $helper->show_toolbar = false;
    $helper->table = $this->table;
    $lang = new Language((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
    $helper->default_form_language = $lang->id;
    $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG') ? Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG') : 0;
    $this->fields_form = array();

    $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
    $helper->submit_action = 'submitCatForm';
    $helper->fields_value['FCI'] = 'ddddd';
    $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false).'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='
    .$this->tab.'&module_name='.$this->name;
    $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');

    return $helper->generateForm(array($fields_form));
}
```

the ajax.php file (the ajax file call the renderForm() function to create new form):

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../init.php');

include_once('catproduct.php'); 
$module = new catproduct(); 
echo $module->renderForm();
```

the done function return nothing . please help me i spend two days searching for solution

Answer (score 0):

Example of ajax call in Prestashop (front-office) :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var form = $('.MyForm');
          form.submit(function(e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../modules/MyModule/controllers/front/MyFrontController.php',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(jsonData) {
                        console.log(jsonData);
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
```

Console shows results. If not, there is a problem with php file.

Here is a sample of PHP file :

```
<?php

include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../init.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../classes/MyUsefulModuleClass.php');
if (Tools::getIsset('my_useful_id')) { 
        echo Tools::jsonEncode('Ajax return fine'));       }?>
```

Check if config.inc.php and init.php are called. Always console.log() your results while working on it.

Then try to separate form creation, you can use only HTML, not sure if you can create forms using helpers, and show it using Ajax. I think that most of modules use HTML only